# Finding connected components of a topology space

Tags: general-topology

I would like to understand how to find the connected components of a given topological space.

I have this example, that I understand:
If I have $\mathbb{Q}$ with the euclidean topology, the connected components are just the singleton elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Proof: If I want to show that the only connected sets are the singletons, I would take a set that is not a singleton and I call it $C$. There exist $x,y\in C$ such that $x \neq y$. Then take $(-\infty,i)$ and $(i,\infty)$ as a seperation for $C$ ($i$ being the irrational).

But if I have for example $\mathbb{Q}$ with another topology i.e cofinite or conumerable. Or just $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite or conumerable how should i proceed?

Comment: It depends by the topology that you fixed, so you have to study case by case

Comment: Your proof example involving the usual topology on $\Bbb{Q}$ needs more work; what is $I$. As for the other topologies on $\Bbb{Q}$, you need to sit back and think. What can you about the intersection of any two open sets in the cofinite or coenumerable topologies?

Comment: @RobArthan $i$ is an irrational number. I showed that an arbitrary set isn't connected (I can write it as an union of two subset

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I understand, so I asked in order to receive a hint or an example :(

Comment: Your proof needs more work. If your irrational number $i$ was greater than every element of $C$, then $(-\infty, i)$ and $(i, \infty)$ would not separate $C$. You need to choose an $i$ between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to study case by case. For example cofinite topology on an infinite set is connected simply because there are no disjoint open subsets in it. As you can see this is a very different approach from the one you used for the standard $\mathbb{Q}$.

There is no general method, unfortunately. There are some tools (e.g. continuous image of a connected space is connected), but ultimately it boils down to some level of cleverness.